# sumar array con decimales array_sum

Tags: php

Estoy intentando sumar un array que tiene decimales pero no logro sumarlo, sin embargo si que me suma los números sin decimales.

Mirando por internet ví que si los decimales es con '.' si que los suma, pero si es com ',' no los suma, mi problema es que mis decimales están con , debido a que los obtengo desde un documento externo ajeno a mí.

```
$total = array_sum($value);
```

Los datos son de este tipo 2,10 - 0,5 - 1 - 0,75 - 4...

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones de hacerlo, aquí te dejo dos:

1. Con foreach:

```php
<?php

$total_suma = 0;
foreach($array_de_valores as $value) {
  $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
  $total_suma += (float)$value;
}
```

Pudes verlo [aquí en funcionamiento](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3bf926b71178cfb0e40e9f92cc9192b6bca7cbf1)

2. `array_map` y `array_sum` :

```php
<?php

function aNumero($cadena) {
  return (float)str_replace(',', '.', $cadena);
}

$array_de_valores = array_map('aNumero', $array_de_valores);
$total_suma = array_sum($array_de_valores);
```

Puedes verlo [aquí en funcionamiento](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cd373073379c553c6d568bc213cda5d29539b328)

Answer (score 0):

podrias intentar usar **str_replace** si el numero que estas intentando sumar es 2,10 php lo interpretara como string, reemplazar las comas por puntos y luego castear a float

```
$value = (float) str_replace(",", ".", $value);
```

para poder tener el valor en numerico

Comment: No me funcioná, no se si esque no lo aplico bien :/

Comment: podrias mostrar mas codigo, modifica tu pregunta para tener mas detalles, por ejemplo agrega de donde sacas $value, que formato tiene el archivo que estas leyendo, etc